# Move a project to module using CVS in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I have new project recently checked into CVS via Eclipse. But I have mistakenly forgot to mention the module name. Now I wanted to move to a module, how can I do that? If I cannot how to to delete the project from CVS from both branch and HEAD.

Please let me know if I need to provide any further details.

Comment: Experts please help me!!!